Looking for a short story on chess, maybe published in Playboy decades ago?
Many years ago a friend received a massive collection of antique Playboy magazines.  Hundreds of them, dating from the 1950s to the 1980s, if I recall.  One of them had a chess short story, and I'm trying to find the name and author of that story.  The plot was of a strong amateur chess player who was sent to prison for some crime, and while in prison receives training from a master.  He is released from prison, then plays his old master's nemesis, and wins.  I know that's not a lot to go on, but any help would be appreciated!

Real-life stories: Claude Bloodgood and someone on a chess forum. More usefully, someone on another forum remembers the same story as you, with more details.

I read it for the articles!!

This sounds very much like The King is Dead (the literal meaning of "checkmate") by Walter Tevis. It was published in Playboy in September 1973.
The main character is Will Schneider, an amateur chess player who is jailed for embezzlement. In prison he meets Baskin, a much stronger chess player with a FIDE rating of over two thousand. Baskin trains him to improve his game, starting with verbal chess, played without a board:

They played verbal chess every evening for a week before Will got his
first draw game. And then a stalemate. And, finally, after three weeks
and over fifty games, Baskin blundered and left a rook hanging. Will,
his voice trembling as he called the move, snapped it off with a
knight fork. And traded the grand master down until he, Will, got to
say, for the first time, that lovely ancient and potent word,
“Checkmate.”

Baskin trains Will in particular to counter the typical playing style of the man who had entrapped him into being sent to jail, Thomas Jefferson Wharton. When Will is released he indeed carries out Baskin's request and challenges Wharton to a game

 and ends up beating him twice, first playing black, and then as white.

Apart from its publication in Playboy, it was also included in Tevis' collection of short stories, The King is Dead.

That sounds like it exactly.  Thanks very much for your help!

@MarshallKaiser Glad to help! Can you click the checkmark by my answer to "accept" it? Then people will know that the question has been answered.

Good find! Would you care to post a comment on this forum thread with the name of the story too, just in case anyone over there is/was trying to identify the same story? (It's not an ID thread, as such, but several people were remembering the same story and nobody mentioned its name.)

Do you have an account there? If you do, maybe you could post the answer yourself (I'm not much of a chess player, so I don't really want/need to register there.)
